# PHP static counter?

Tags: php, variables, static

I'm trying to create a script that will retain a count, even when it is called multiple times. This is to give unique IDs to certain things lines that the script is writing to a file.

For exmaple:

```
Monday I call the script and make 2 lines. The script gives ID 1 and 2 to those lines.
Friday I call the script again and make another line. The script gives ID 3 to this one.
etc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using MySQL's auto increment feature.

Otherwise, store a flat file to store a running count (and lock it when in use to avoid concurrency issues).

Comment: So you mean just write the current number to a file? How do I prevent someone from manually editing it?

Comment: How do you prevent someone from editing a file on your webserver? Your webserver is seriously misconfigured has a serious security flaw if that is the case. 

If you want to prevent people from viewing the file, then store it outside the document root.

Comment: @MaxMackie: If you are developing a web page the manipulation has to occur on the server. No one should be able to that. If its a local script you will give to others, this is truly possible.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't thinking, I've been working on the server for so long developing other things I forgot people don't see what I look at :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this using static variables. The variable will lose its value if the scripts end. You could save your information in any storage type you want (MySQL, text file, xml ...).

Answer (score 1):

How about reading the ID of the last line added and just increasing it by one? PHP isn't that strict with data types, so it's quite easy to do something like

```
$a = "1";
$a = (int)$a;
$a++;
// write $a for next line
```

Comment: or simply: `$a = count(file('path/to/file)) + 1;`

Comment: Well, what if the files are stored seperately, say, one per month, but the ID should be unique over all files? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, also it's not in the question, this could be a problem. But in that case, one could just add all lines of all file and increment that sum by one.

Comment: Okay, that's one way... there are problems with both solutions. Mine will have difficulties if there are seperate files too I guess

Comment: Yeah, but I guess, John Cartwrights solution is propably far better then looking "inside" the files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not already interacting with a database, the best answer for you might be SQLite.  (SQLite is an SQL-accessible database stored in a flat file, allowing basic database functions without the need for a persistent server.  It's accessed in PHP using PDO. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php)

Otherwise, reading the file is probably the easiest way.  There's an exponentially smarter and more efficient way to do this using fseek, but it's too early for me to figure it out.

```
<?php
    $file = fopen($theFilename, 'r');
    while ($line = fscanf($file));   //Ugly, but the last value of $line will be the last line of the file. (Super cumbersome if the file is big.)
    $array = explode($line, '|') // Or whatever delimiter you're using to separate data
    $last_id = $array[0] // Assuming the ID is in the first place in the file.
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look into this if my current plan fails.